# While installing pandas on python 3.4.3, getting error - No module tempita

Tags: python, pandas, cython

While installing pandas on python 3.4.3, getting error - No module named tempita.
I get this error even though Tempita is already installed.

1.) `pip install pandas`

2.) Below error is occuring - it says to `pip install tempita`

3.) I did `pip install tempita`, (already installed), it says:

```
Requirement already satisfied: Tempita in ./.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (0.5.2)
```

Please help me installing pandas. I am able to pip install numpy. I am installing it on godaddy web hosting.

```
************Error Log for pip install pandas******************************
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/happygivings/.local/bin/python3.4 /home/happygivings/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp66tw0gn1
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-tlql2aud/pandas

  Complete output (34 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    **File "setup.py", line 101, in <module>
      from Cython import Tempita as tempita**
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3kwrrpmv/overlay/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Tempita/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
      from ._tempita import *
  ImportError: /tmp/pip-build-env-3kwrrpmv/overlay/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Tempita/_tempita.cpython-34m.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "setup.py", line 103, in <module>
      import tempita
  **ImportError: No module named 'tempita'**

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/happygivings/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 257, in <module>
      main()
    File "/home/happygivings/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 240, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/home/happygivings/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 91, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3kwrrpmv/overlay/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 146, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3kwrrpmv/overlay/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 127, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3kwrrpmv/overlay/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 237, in run_setup
      self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3kwrrpmv/overlay/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 105, in <module>
      raise ImportError('Building pandas requires Tempita: '
  ImportError: Building pandas requires Tempita: pip install Tempita


  ---------------------log of pip install pandas-------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/happygivings/.local/bin/python3.4 /home/happygivings/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp66tw0gn1 Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install Tempita`?

Comment: I used pip install pandas. I think it installs the latest version. python version in 3.4.3

Comment: What is the output of `pip --version`?

Comment: i have tried pip3 install Tempita as well. I got below:
Requirement already satisfied: Tempita in ./.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (0.5.2).

Comment: pip version is 19.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3.4 is very old, either update it or install older version of pandas. I belive v.0.19.2 is suitable

```
pip install pandas==0.19.2
```

Comment: I got a different error with this version. Pandas got installed with version:0.19.2. Thank you very much for your help.